# Yii2: $loadedModules does not show all modules

Tags: php, yii2, yii-modules

Created module *"forum"* - exactly as written [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html). Then created nested module *"admin"*:

```
//"Module.php" in '@app/modules/forum'
namespace app\modules\forum;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        \Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));

        $this->modules = [
            'admin' => [
                // here is my nested module
                'class' => 'app\modules\forum\modules\admin\Module',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Also created a non-nested module *"games"* (in the same way) and wrote in *"web.php"* (main config-file):

```
'modules' => [
    'forum' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\forum\Module',
    ],
    'games' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\games\Module',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\forum\modules\admin\Module',
    ],
],
```

But when I tried to output:

```
// codeline is written in application view, not in module view
var_dump(array_keys(\Yii::$app->loadedModules));
```

I saw only these modules:

```
array(4) {
  string(19) "yii\web\Application"
  string(16) "yii\debug\Module"
  string(14) "yii\gii\Module"
  string(24) "app\modules\forum\Module"
```

}

*"Games"* and nested *"admin"* modules are absent! Although [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#nested-modules) says:

> $loadedModules property keeps a list of loaded modules, **including both direct children and nested ones**, indexed by their class names.

But I could get only *"forum"* myself-created module. What am I understanding wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documentation says:

> $loadedModules property keeps a list of loaded modules

which mean that it keeps modules that loaded in current request. E.g. if you are on module's page `example.com/forum/` it will contain `app\modules\forum\Module` but if you on `example.com/site` where *site* is controller's name `$loadedModules` will contain only modules that are set in `$bootstrap` config property.

To get list of all modules call `Yii::$app->modules`.  Note that `$loadedModules` contains app itself since it extends `Module` class. `Yii::$app->modules` contains all modules from app config `modules` property.

Comment: Thanks! And I noticed, that `$loadedModules` will contain **NOT exactly only** modules that are set in `$bootstrap` config property. If u noticed, in `contact` page I saw also _app\modules\forum\Module_, which is NOT in bootstrap. It's because for purpose of experiment I called `\Yii::$app->getModule('forum');` in `contact` view - thus I **loaded via getModule() method** one more module - `forum`. I added `\Yii::$app->getModule('forum')->getModule('admin');` - `admin` module now is also present in `$loadedModules`! The same situation with `games` module. Unexpected behavior for Yii2-beginner)

Comment: Yes, you're right, when you call `\Yii::$app->getModule();` the module will appear in `$loadedModules`